# How to download >1 MB Email attachment using EWS in C#

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I need to Download Email Attachments from Exchange Server using Exchange Web Service API 2.1
I was tried **FindItemResults**. Minimum size of files can be download. but, If the file size is above 1 MB(I tried with 2MB file). It takes More time and throw Time expired Exception. I know Why this exception. But My question is,
can I download big size of attachments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **GetItem**, not **FindItem**. Use **FindItem** to get the Id och the mail with the attachment, then get the entire mail with **GetItem**.

> Note that the FindItem operation only returns the first 512 bytes (255
>   Unicode characters) of any property; therefore, message header
>   collections that are longer than 512 bytes will be truncated.

You can modify the code in this great answer to suit your needs: [Exchange Web Services API : get mail attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725774/exchange-web-services-api-get-mail-attachments)

Comment: yes, I get item id with Service.FindItems(), and get all email properties of each Email with EmailMessage.Load().

Comment: @SureshKumar Try the link in the answer and see if it help!

Answer (score 1):

The default timeout in the EWS Managed API is 90 seconds so if the download isn't completing in that time you'll get a time out exception thrown. You can just increase the timeout by setting the timeout property on the ExchangeService class eg

Service.Time = 300000;

300000 = 300000 milliseconds or 5 minutes

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Yes I already set this property.  that time I had worst net speed. So I have seen this Exception. My Question is Can it download or Not? I checked after some time. My code working Perfectly. 
FindItem returns only the first 512 bytes. So I have doubt with FindItemResults. So only I asked this Q

Comment: As Tholie's anwser say not with FindItems, What are you trying to do ? your question says your trying to download attachment which you would need to use both GetItem (to get the AttachmentId's) then GetAttachment.operations for

Comment: Get itemID from Service.FindItems(...), then add Attachment Properties into EmailMessageSchema, then call EmailMessage.load(), it returns the attachmens ID. then I use fileAttachment.load() for download that attachment. all are working fine. I have troubled with my net Speed. So that downlads getting failed. Now All are Working Fine.